# How to create a list of list of given size and initialize with values in java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, collections

This is the code to initialize a list of list with some values and given size in C++

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> arr = vector<>(rowSize, vector<>(colSize, value));
```

Is there any equivalent code in Java?

We could use the IntStream.range() to stream and create new List and add it to the main list. Then loop through the 2D list and set some default values.
I'm searching for something similar to c++ implementation mentioned above

Comment: So `List<List<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>()`?

Comment: Do not tag `dsa`.  Please read what the tag stands for:  the `dsa` tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that:

```
Supplier<List<Integer>> s = Stream.generate(() -> value)
      .limit(colSize)
      .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new)); 
List<List<Integer>> table = Stream.generate(s)
  .limit(rowSize)
  .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

But it may be overkill to use `Stream` for that:

```
List<Integer> columnTemplate = Collections.nCopies(colSize, value);
List<List<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<>(rowSize); 
for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) {
  table.add(new ArrayList<>(columnTemplate)); // because list is immutable
}
```

As you can see, I used version that do no return immutable collection: you would probably want to be able to change the value at some row/col:

```
table.get(row).set(col, n);
```

This will fail if you use `toList()` on `Stream` or `nCopies` directly.

Comment: Or just `List<List<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(rowSize, Collections.nCopies(colSize, value))); table.replaceAll(ArrayList::new);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.nCopies` for a `List` of primitives filled with a certain value. To create the `List` of `List`s, you can use `Stream.generate` (to ensure that each row is a separate reference).

For example:

```java
int value = 1, rowSize = 3, colSize = 10;
List<List<Integer>> list = Stream.generate(() -> 
       (List<Integer>)new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(colSize, value)))
       .limit(rowSize).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: I don't think the cast is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing this, and both take a generic type for the value.

Traditional for loop, or with streams.

**Note:** The `Collections.nCopies` method returns an immutable list, so you will need to pass it to the `ArrayList` constructor if you intend to modify it.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> intMatrix1 = initializeMatrix(3, 4, 1);
        List<List<Integer>> intMatrix2 = initializeMatrix2(3, 4, 1);

        System.out.println(intMatrix1); // [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
        System.out.println(intMatrix2); // [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
    }

    public static <E> List<List<E>> initializeMatrix(int rows, int cols, E value) {
        List<List<E>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
            List<E> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
                row.add(colIndex, value);
            }
            matrix.add(row);
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    public static <E> List<List<E>> initializeMatrix2(int rows, int cols, E value) {
        return Stream.generate(() -> new ArrayList<>(Collections
                .nCopies(cols, value)))
                .limit(rows)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: In recent versions of Java you can simply use `.toList()` instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())` but this is going to return an immutable list.

Comment: Yes, they typically both will. I wasn't saying to use the shorter version to get a modifiable list, I was pointing out that there's a shorter version, and that this code (with either one) will most likely fail for OP if the  list is going to be modified.